# How do I implement multiform validation in ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have 3 tables:

> TableMaster <-- TableDetails1 (One-Many relation)
>   TableMaster <-- TableDetails2

How can I implement this just on a single page using ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor?
I think I should use multiform and validation for each form, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need multiple forms. Sorry if I misunderstood your question

```
@model TableMaster

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)

    @foreach(int i = 0; i < Model.TableDetails1.Count; i++)
    {
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.TableDetails1[i].Name)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you be more specific please?

If you are just collecting data, and whole form is submited only once, use model like that:

```
public class MyBigForm
{
   public MyForm1 Form1 { get; set; }
   public MyForm2 Form2 { get; set; }
   public MyForm3 Form3 { get; set; }
}
```

Each class (MyForm1-3) can have own validation.

---

But if you are using Ajax or somethig to load detail forms, is not simply possible in MVC to validate all forms at once. Then you will have to write custom jquery validation into ajax response (after data receive) and then into Controller.